# How to dismiss the fragment loaded in framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, android-framelayout

i use these line to remove the fragment, I am getting the log at the end but this two lines does not works

DPFragment frag = new DPFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();

This is my MainActivity in which i used tab listner

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if(isActiveFrame){

                DPFragment frag = new DPFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();

                isActiveFrame =false;

            }else
            {

            }
        }
```

This is my ActivityMain.xml

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.myproject.externals.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_CustomViewPager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I use this line to load the fragement

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_main, new DPFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: you are removing another instance of that DPFragment, so you gonna need  keep the fragment global in order to remove it after.

Comment: when i given this line  " getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fl_main)).commit(); "  instead I am getting error  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference @tebitoq

Comment: Is `DPFragment ` a framework fragment or a support fragment ? It seems that you are adding it with the framework `FragmentManager` and removing it with the support `FragmentManager`. This does not work

Comment: @bwt I am using both support framework manger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the line

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
```

with the lines

```
  if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fl_main) != null) {

                    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                }
```

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating new DPFragment instance `DPFragment frag = new DPFragment();` keep it as a class variable.

So your code should be like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
       private DPFragment frag;
       ...
           @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        frag = new DPFragment();
        //use the DPFragment instance frag for adding it to CustomViewPager
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (isActiveFrame) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
                    isActiveFrame = false;
                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```